# Below C code runs on Fedora, however on RaspberryPi 1, gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c, opencv, gcc, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm trying to compile the below C code on Fedora 23 computer (gcc version 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2) (GCC)) and it gives no errors. And program runs.

However when I'm compile the same code on Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+ (gcc version 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) ), compiler gives no errors but crashes when running.Can someone figure out, where's the issue?

Debug info also attached.

```
/* Compile with
* gcc -lm opencv_video_isolated.c -o ooopencv_video_isolated `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        CvCapture* capture;

        capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

        IplImage* frame;

        /* Capture a single frame from the video stream */
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );


        double ab = frame->depth;
        double ac = frame->width;
        double ad = frame->height;



        return 0;
    }
```

**Also I've pasted the GDB output on Raspberry Pi.**

```
(gdb) file opencv_video_isolated
Reading symbols from opencv_video_isolated...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/.../src/opencv_video_isolated 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xb30ec270 (LWP 1523)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00012718 in main () at opencv_video_isolated.c:22
22      double ab = frame->depth;
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00012718 in main () at opencv_video_isolated.c:22
(gdb)
```

Comment: you may want to add some basic defensive programming techniques like checking return values.

Answer (score 2):

> `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

You'll want to `print frame`. Most likely it's `NULL`. Then you'll need to figure out what preconditions of `cvQueryFrame` or `cvCreateCameraCapture` you've violated.

Comment: Yes. Problem was `cvQueryFrame` was returning an **NULL**. Is there a best practical method to defensive test than below?


`    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if(!frame)
        printf("cvQueryFrame Failed\n");`